# How to change colors of a cell of collection view on scrolling swift5

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

i want to change color of the cell of my collectionview on scrolling in swift.
here is an image of my viewcontroller. i want to change background color of the specific cell to white on scroll. and i used animatedcollectionViewLayout for animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, call it in `scrollViewDidScroll`. Don't use `indexPathsForVisibleItems`、`visibleCells`, they have a few issues.

```swift
    func updateCellsApperance() {
        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: modesCollectionView.contentOffset, size: modesCollectionView.frame.size)
        let center = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
        
        var indexPaths: Set<IndexPath> = []
        let step = 10.0
        var x = center.x
        while x > visibleRect.minX {
            if let indexPath = modesCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: center.y)) {
                indexPaths.insert(indexPath)
            }
            x -= step
        }
        x = center.x + step
        while x < visibleRect.maxX {
            if let indexPath = modesCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: center.y)) {
                indexPaths.insert(indexPath)
            }
            x += step
        }
        
        indexPaths.forEach { indexPath in
            if let cell = modesCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath),
                let attrs = modesCollectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) {
                let distanceX = visibleRect.midX - attrs.center.x
                // >= 0.0
                let ratio = abs(distanceX) * (1.0 / attrs.frame.width)
                cell.xxx.color = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: max(0.0, 1.0 - ratio), blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```